# Scala Blocking Map

Tags: java, multithreading, mongodb, scala, csv

I am using Scala in a project and I have the following situation:

I am reading a csv file and I have the following structure:

```
mail,file,action
ex1@...,file1,insert
ex2@...,file2,update
```

I have three collections in my mongodb: users, files, actions and; Actions makes reference to file and user ids.

The schema would be something like this:

```
Action {
 actionName: String,
 userId: ObjectId, 
 fileId: ObjectId 
}
```

The thing is that I don't have these Ids when I am reading the csv. They are created during the process of reading. So my main problem is: **How to reference users and files when they're inserted at the moment you're trying to use them**.

My initial solution was to create 3 treads to save each part of the code and use two maps: Map1[userMail,Ids] and Map2[fileName,Ids]. After inserting an user or file in the database, the code would take their respective ids and put in the map.

In the meantime, I have a thread that saves the actions. This thread keeps pooling those maps for when it has both ids. Whenever it has, it will save the action (let's call it "the action thread"). Something like this:

```
while(filesMap.get(action.fileId) == None) {
  Thread.sleep(1000)
}
while(usersMap.get(action.userId) == None) {
  Thread.sleep(1000)
} ... //save code omitted for clarity
```

This code works, but the problem is that it is too slow. I believe that the "action thread" is locking the map all the time with its pooling, preventing some writes from the thread that is actually saving data to the db.

So, my question is: Is there a smarter way to notify the "action thread" that the ids are there and remove the pooling code or, Is there a better way of doing it out of the box in **scala**?

I did something similar in Javascript using promises and resolve, but since I am working for less than a month with Scala, I don't know how to port the code.

Thanks

Comment: [Futures and Promises](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html) is a good read. How large are these csv files?

Comment: 1.5Million lines coming from a stream. It worked well up to some thousand of lines. But then it got too fat.

Comment: Sorry for the newbie question but, do you think 1.5M is too much? It's ok if I can process it in up to two mins I guess.

Answer (score 1):

> How to reference users and files when they're inserted at the moment you're trying to use them

You need a join.

> mongodb

Stream everything in a real database and do the join there. Doing it in Scala is basically re-implementing half a database by hand...

If you have unlimited memory, you could loading everything in Scala immutable collections:

```
val filesMap: Map[Int, File] = ...
val userMap: Map[Int, User] = ...

val actions: Stream[Action] =
  csv.lines.map(csvParser).flatMap { case (actionName, userId, fileId) =>
    for {
      file <- filesMap.get(fileId)
      user <- userMap.get(userId)
    } yield
      Action(actionName, user, file)
  }
```

Comment: In this approach you consider that the files and users are already read. The thing is I don't have this map filled. I am filling it while I am reading the actions

Answer (score 0):

Scala objects are not designed for multithread access. You suppose to use actors in scala.

But I guess you need to do polling. It is possible, just use Java

java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html

Scala works great with Java classes.

[image]

Comment: This is wrong. See [TrieMap](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/concurrent/TrieMap.html) for example.